# COM Exception silently eaten

Tags: native, windbg, managed

I have a native exe loading managed code that calls a COM object. The managed code attempts to  set up a call back using IConnectionPoint. However the Advise method on the COM side returns E_FAIL. A manged COMException is thrown but my code does not catch the exception and I am not sure where it is handled. In fact I am modifying the COM code to set up a status flag to indicate connection status... a kludge I could avoid if the COMException could only be caught.  I can see the COM exception in Windbg but the stack trace on the exception is empty. Any suggestion as to how to find out where the exception is being swallowed.

Comment: In Windbg, are you able to break when the COM exception occurs? If so, you can get either native stack (k) or managed stack (!clrstack) at that point. Also, you can either stop on (!soe) the exception or just issue a sxe clr to break on all .NET exceptions.

Comment: @Dono He wants to break where the exception is caught, not thrown.